# Remove double quotes in json_encode return

Tags: php, json, laravel, encode

Here is my response of

```
{"success":"1","kids":"[{ StudentId : 1, Student Name : Sampsons Alec},
{ StudentId : 3, Student Name : Craig Jacob},{ StudentId : 4, Student Name : Tumblin Jonathan,}]"}
```

But i want it as

```
{"success":"1","kids":[{ StudentId : 1, Student Name : Sampsons Alec},
{ StudentId : 3, Student Name : Craig Jacob},{ StudentId : 4, Student Name : Tumblin Jonathan,}]}
```

i.e., to remove the double quotes that is in the kids data of the json

How can i do this ?

**Note :**

```
return $KidsData;
```

gives

```
[{ StudentId : 1, Student Name : Sampsons Alec},
    { StudentId : 3, Student Name : Craig Jacob},{ StudentId : 4, Student Name : Tumblin Jonathan,}]
```

But When return after json_encode it is adding double quotes like the response i given first.

```
    $Response = array(
            'success' => '1',
            'kids' => $KidsData
        );
 return json_encode($Response);
```

How can i fix this ?

**Update :**

**I don't bother if the json becomes invalid**

Comment: Why do you want to remove the quotes? That would make the JSON invalid.

Comment: It looks like the server code needs to be changed.

Comment: Also the string contained within the variable `$KidsData` is invalid JSON by itself (in case you were thinking of using it as an array of objects for the `kids` key).

Comment: If any how it become possible, that have no mean because when you write json_decode(//your encoded data); it will give error due to removal of double quotes.

Comment: can you send the php code how you are initializing [$kidsData]..

Comment: @Bogdan : I won't bother if the json becomes invalid. Can you say how to do that ?

Comment: If you want to return a response which is not valid JSON, you can't use `json_encode` because that function only returns valid JSON. You'll need to build the string manually and return as a [reponse](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#basic-responses) with whatever headers you feel appropriate.

Comment: Please post some more code. `$KidsData` appears to be a JSON encoded string already. From where do you get that variable?

Comment: Is it possible to do that manually ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible `return '{"success":"1","kids":' . $KidsData . '}';`, though I cannot possibly understand why you would be ok with returning invalid JSON.

Comment: Thanks i did that way and got the result. I need this invalid json for the web service where mobile developer needs it .. If you post it (Invalid JSON :p ) as answer it would accept it :) Thanks :)